# Check voice mail different ext in RingCentral

Tags: ringcentral, voicemail

We are using SoftPhones and Desktop apps currently exploring RingCentral.

Is there any way by which admin can easily view the voicemails of other extensions getting into the extension explicitly?

This will help admin to monitor the voicemail for all the users and their extensions.

I searched for solution but didn't get any in the net.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no such feature available and maybe made available in future.

I can see the same idea is submitted in the RingCentral community:

https://community.ringcentral.com/idea/27191/voicemail-of-other-extensions.html

Also as an workaround it is suggested to add a second email address to the voicemail notifications, and made sure to check the box "include voicemail as attachment".

You can now check everyone's VMs in your email.

Also make sure you log into `online admin portal` and select Users with extension and in Notification section Voicemail Messages > "By Email" box to get this feature.